# Elm List type mismatch

Tags: list, functional-programming, elm

I was following an (old?) [tutorial](http://elm-by-example.org/Chapter2FibonacciBars.html) and I got a type mismatch. Has the List library changed from 0.14.1 to 0.15? [elmpage](http://elm-lang.org/learn/courses/beginner/Lists-and-Records.elm).

Code:

```
module Fibonacci where

import List exposing (..)

fibonacci : Int -> List Int
fibonacci n =
   let fibonacci1 n acc =
           if n <= 2
               then acc
               else fibonacci1 (n-1) ((head acc + (tail >> head) acc) :: acc)
   in
       fibonacci1 n [1,1] |> reverse
```

Type mismatch:

```
Type mismatch between the following types on line 11, column 40 to 69:

        number

        Maybe.Maybe a

    It is related to the following expression:

        (head acc) + ((tail >> head) acc)

Type mismatch between the following types on line 11, column 52 to 64:

        Maybe.Maybe

        List

    It is related to the following expression:

        tail >> head
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm afraid both of those are old(er) material (than 0.15). Elm 0.15 uses core 2.0.1, in which (as the version suggests) there are breaking changes.
The one you're running into is that `head` and `tail` now return a `Nothing` instead of crashing on empty lists. When the list isn't empty, you get the head/tail, wrapped in a `Just`. These two constructors are of the `Maybe` type.

Here's some updated code (which doesn't need head/tail):

```
fibonacci : Int -> List Int
fibonacci goal =
    let fibonacciHelp n a b fibs =
        if n >= goal
            then List.reverse fibs
            else fibonacciHelp (n+1) (a + b) a (a :: fibs)
    in
        fibonacciHelp 0 1 0 []
```

## Sources:

- [Similar question on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elm-discuss/XJeMaArsw04/discussion)
- [Source of the above code snippet](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elm-discuss/XJeMaArsw04/tjliHd6K3mAJ) in that discussion, written by Evan Czaplicki